# How to make in-app purchase premium feature free for certain users without going through credit card processing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Currently, to check whether a user had purchased a premium feature, we did the following query in `onQueryInventoryFinished`.

Note, we do not store in-app purchase status locally for security purpose. We perform query to Google in-app purchase server every-time during app startup. **This works extremely fine so far without customer complain.**

```
// Do we have the premium upgrade?
Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(org.yccheok.jstock.gui.billing.Utils.SKU_PREMIUM);
boolean mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && org.yccheok.jstock.gui.billing.Utils.verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
```

Recently, due to marketing activities, we would like to make this premium feature free for certain loyal users. For instance, the user had shared this app with 20 people.

Is there any way we can programmatic access to Google in-app purchase server, so that we can make SKU_PREMIUM true for certain users, without having to go through credit card processing?

If not, this is the only way we can think off. **But, we prefer not to involve our own server for reliability purpose.** We would like to make the entire premium feature checking, by solely communicating with Google in-app purchase server.

1. Check whether this user had shared this app with 20 people, by querying our own server
2. If yes, turn on `mIsPremium` flag in Android app.
3. If not, talk to Google in-app purchase server, perform normal in-app purchase status query flow, by executing `onQueryInventoryFinished`

Is there any other way we can try, without involving our own server, during premium feature status query?

Comment: You could use https://developers.google.com/appengine You would need to write the applet but at least it is Google's servers handling the processing.